# Position tooltip relative to it's parent

Tags: jquery, position

I have the following code;

```
var posLeft = 170;
var posDown = e.pageY;

    $(this).next().css({'top':posDown, 'left':posLeft, 'position':'absolute'}).toggleClass('is-hidden');
});
```

and HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">123</a>
        <div class="pop-up is-hidden">
            <p>Type:<span>Code</span></p>
            <p>Number:<span>123</span></p>
            <p>Status:<span>Valid</span></p>
            <p>Sold In:<span>August</span></p>
            <p>Uploaded:<span>20/09/2012 10:34</span></p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>Valid</td>
    <td>Device is active</td>
</tr>
```

The jQuery shows the `.pop-up` div on hover, the problem I have is with the vertical positioning of `.pop-up`. It sit's the left correctly, but the vertical positioning is out. I think using pageY is positioning the div relatively to the document, when I would like it to be positioned against the anchor.

The table does not have any positioning applied, so I need help with the best method of getting the `.pop-up` to appear in the right location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/2zY8c/)**?

```
$("a.tooltip").mouseenter(function(e) {
    tooltip = $(this).parent().find(".is-hidden");
    tooltip
        .css("top",(e.pageY) + "px")
        .css("z-index","200002")
        .css("left",(e.pageX) + "px");

    tooltip.show();
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    tooltip = $(this).parent().find(".is-hidden");
    tooltip.hide();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [jquery position method](http://api.jquery.com/position/) on the element that is being clicked.

For example `var posDown = $(this).position().top`

That should give you the right position.

EDIT - Here's a very similar fiddle to SubRed but using `position()` and the height property to position the tooltip http://jsfiddle.net/FUS27/

Comment: That's positioning it more closely, but it's still lower than I would like.

Comment: Check my edit with the fiddle link, you can add the width of the element to the `left` if needs be as well